# Android BottomNavigationView overlaps Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bottomnavigationview

I have a `BottomNavigationView` and both my fragments have a `RecyclerView` which content is partially hidden under the `BottomNavigationView`

Lots of people seem to have had this problem yet I tried all of the answers (make rootview LinearLayout and set height of FrameLayout to 0 etc...) and none of them work.

This is my `activity_main.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/color12"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/color12"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_sample_store">
    </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

this is how I initialize it (MainActivity.java)

```
private void initHandlers()
{
    this.adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            int id = menuItem.getItemId();
            switch (id)
            {
                case R.id.menu_option_local:
                    fragment = new AlphaListFragment(getApplicationContext());
                    break;
                case R.id.menu_option_store:
                    fragment = new BetaListFragment(getApplicationContext());
                    break;
            }
            setActiveFragment(fragment);
            return true;
        }
    });
}

private void setActiveFragment(Fragment fragment)
{
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, fragment).commit();
}
```

And if it might help, this is the xml file of a fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewBeta"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loadingBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

EDIT: SOLUTION FOUND

1. Make the rootview of `activity_main` a `LinearLayout`
2. Set its orientation to vertical
3. Set the `layout_weigth` of the `FrameLayout` to 1
4. Make sure that the `FrameLayout` has a height of 0dp

Comment: You probably need to add a margin bottom to your framelayout with the value of the height of your BottomNavigationView

Comment: Screenshot would go a long way.

Comment: @Wouter Can you please provide the screenshot for more reference